# Comment a code block in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know `ctrl+/` comment a single line; I also know `ctrl+shift+/` creates a block comment. What I want to do is **commenting a code block**, for example in the following figure, I want to comment all codes within `__init__` function. What is the *shortcut*/*command name* for this?

I'm also interested in **selecting** this code block, which may help me delete it quicker.

[image]

Comment: collapse the block (fold), select the block, `Ctrl+/`, if you comment all INSIDE the `__init__` you have a syntax error

Comment: How do I select the block? Using cursor?

Comment: how do you select text?

Comment: You should also show the entire code block so people can see how it ends and starts.